# Can't move controls in VB6

Tags: vb6

I'm working on a small project in VB6, and am trying to fiddle with the positions and sizes of the controls in the Design View. But they won't move or resize; one grabs the little handles and nothing happens. Does anyone know why, and what to do about it?

Comment: Check to make sure the form is not locked.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try right-clicking on your form (*not* any of the controls on it,) and unchecking Lock Controls.

The option can also be found at the end of the standard toolbar, and will look like this when locked: [image: Lock toggled on]

Answer (score 4):

Is the form read-only?  This might prevent you from resizing. 
You might want to check the overall options (might have snap to grid on, which would prevent very small changes.)

Comment: Thank you. It wasn't either of those things, but it might have been.